# Implementing a finite difference method in Mathematica

Tags: finite-difference, mathematica

I am trying to iterate the following equation
$$
x_{k}(n+1)=x_k (n)-\epsilon (x_{k+1}(n)-2x_k(n) +x_{k-1}(n))+\sqrt{\epsilon}\; \eta_{k}(n)
$$
where $n$ denotes which time step I'm on and $k$ is the location on the string with periodic boundary conditions, $\epsilon$ is the size of the time step and $\eta$ is a random variate from a gaussian distribution with mean 0 and variance 1.  $\eta$ is re-picked after each time step and is varies from location to location. I generated my initial $x$ randomly with

```
x[0] = RandomReal[{0, π}, 10]
```

which gives me 10 real numbers between 0 and $\pi$, which are my 1D lattice site variables.  I then define $\eta$ by

```
η[0] = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 10]
```

which gives me 10 random numbers from my distribution. I am taking the time step to be $\epsilon =1/100$ Then to define my iteration equation I write

```
x[[j]][n_ + 1] := x[[j]][n] - ϵ (x[[j + 1]][n] - 2 x[[j]][n] + x[[j + 1]][n]) + Sqrt[ϵ] η[[j]][n]
```

but this failed to iterate when I tried when just looking at a sigle site and its neighbors.  If someone could be so kind as to help me put in periodic boundary conditions, as well as to get the iteration to work, I would be grateful.  I am using Mathematica 8.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In Mathematica I recommend do this with Sparse Matrix-Vector products as follows. First I will define a circulant matrix $C$ (with the periodic BCs) which appears on the RHS of your equation.

In matrix notation your equation reads
\begin{equation}
x(n+1) = x(n) + \epsilon C x(n) + \sqrt{\epsilon} \eta(n)
\end{equation}
or 
\begin{equation}
x(n+1) = (I + \epsilon C) x(n) + \sqrt{\epsilon} \eta(n)
\end{equation}

So, here are the matrix definitions. The classical (-1 2 -1) stiffness matrix is:

```
StiffnessMatrix[n_] := SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 2., Band[{1, 2}] -> -1., 
   Band[{2, 1}] -> -1.}, {n, n}, 0.];
```

From this definition the circulant matrix is constructed with a simple adjustment.

```
CirculantMatrix[n_] := Block[{K = StiffnessMatrix[n]}, 
   ReplacePart[K, {{1, n} -> -1., {n, 1} -> -1.}]];
```

For a given $n$ (size of your system) we the define

```
C = CirculantMatrix[n];
```

The identity matrix can be computed with IdentityMatrix[n]. Conversely, a sparse implementation reads

```
Eye[n_] := SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 1.}, {n, n}, 0.];
```

So, to implement $A = (I + \epsilon C)$ we write

```
A = Eye[n] + eps C;
```

We are now ready to iterate:

```
x = x + A.x + sqe eta;
```

where $sqe = Sqrt[eps]$.

The following implementation is for a noise $\eta$ which is independent of position. You can adjust it for your needs.

```
Iteration[nmax_, eps_, size_] := With[{
   A = Eye[size] + eps CirculantMatrix[size],
   x0 = RandomReal[{0, \[Pi]}, size],
   sqe = N@Sqrt[eps]
  },
    NestList[A.# + sqe RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], size] &, x0, nmax]];
```

Input is the number of iterations *nmax*, the $\epsilon$ guy *eps* and the size of your system (which in you example is 10). Output is a matrix where each entry (e.g. `sol[[1]]`) is the state of your system at a given time. 
If you want only the last output, either use `Last` in your output or replace `NestList` with `Nest`.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I coded something in mathematica so I'll write in fortranish pseudocode instead

```
ntimesteps = 20
nx = 10
x = array(0:nx+1, 0:ntimesteps)
x[1:nx,0] = RandomReal(0,pi)
// boundary conditions:
x[0,0] = x[nx,0]
x[nx+1,0] = x[1,0]
do i=1,ntimesteps
  eta[1:nx] = RandomNormalDistribution(0,1)
  do j=1,nx
    x[j][i] = x[j,i-1] - eps(x[j-1,i-1]-2x[j,i-1]+x[j+1,i-1]) + sqrt(eps)eta[j]
  enddo
  x[0,i] = x[nx,i]
  x[nx+1,i] = x[1,i]
enddo
```

Note that in the formula of the iteration you gave there are two mistakes:
First use n_ instead of n_+1, secondly you have two j+1 instead of one j+1 and one j-1